# Adding Two Section different Cells in a Single Section grouped table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've used two different sections in a `TableView`,meanwhile `first section cell is dynamic` and `second section cell is static`.Here i need both cell have mix in a single section without header title.here is the picture

[image]

the above picture i need to add Static Cell into the, first section--> bottom of the first cell ,and first cell is the dynamically increase the row count ,here is my code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2;
```

}

and number of rows

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

int count;
        switch (section) {
            case 0:
                count = [nameArray count];
                break;
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"section called");       // This line is logged
                count = 1;
                break;
            default:
                count = 0;
                break;
        }
        return count;

}
```

But i need like this,

[image]

i want without second section header,  static cell add to the First section.Can you please suggest me how can i solve this issue,thank you.

Comment: G.P.Reddy : Dude whats the issue ???? You want to show header for second section ??? return a view for the second section header in ViewForHeaderInSection and you will see it. I din get your question

Comment: why do you want to put the static and dynamic cell into two separate sections? why don't you just put both them in one section, and set the header for that section ?

Comment: i want static cell add to the first section ,In the first section > first cell is dynamic count @SandeepBhandari

Answer (score 0):

// you can handle dynamic height and header views by using following delegate methods of tableview

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(HBTableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch (section) {
        case 0:
             return 60;
        case 1:
             return 40;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }

}



- (UIView *)tableView:(HBTableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

switch (section) {
        case 0:
             return view1
        case 1:
             return view2
        default:
            return view3
            break;
    }
}
```